# Localization of buttons with images

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have a button with image.How can I localize it, in order it to have another image on different language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading the image from a Storyboard or programmatically?

If programmatically, then you can localise the string of the file name and have different images for each localisation.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is not in an xcassets you can localize it in the file inspector. 
If you image is in an xcassets, you can include the language identifier in its name, or as @jdapps said, localize the image name in a strings file.

Comment: Thanks! How does language identifier in xcassets look like ? Tried to google, but found nothing.

Comment: Instead of naming your image "myImage", name it "myImage_en", and then use `[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage_%@",localeIdentifier]`

Answer (score 0):

You can add localized names for your images to Localizable.strings file and use "NSLocalizedString(key: String, comment: String)" method to access it. Works great for me.

Answer (score -1):

Select the “image” in the project navigator. Next, bring up the file inspector, and locate the localization section, in which you’ll see a button named “*Localize…*”. Click the button and you’ll be prompted for confirmation. Choose English and click the “Localize” button to confirm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Switch back to the finder and local the project directory. You’ll find two folders: `en.lproj` and `Base.lproj`. Both folders are automatically generated by Xcode for localization. The `en.lproj` folder stores resource files for English localization,If you localise for french language too, then  `fr.lproj` folder will be added and is for French localization. If you look into both folders, each one contains the image file. Download the French version of the cover image from here (or use whatever image you like). Copy the cover image just downloaded and replace the one in `fr.lproj` folder.